# Cyrillic file names broken after upgrading Slackware

Tags: locale, character-encoding, unicode, slackware

After upgrading glibc and some other libraries on Slackware instead of cyrillic names I see the garbage:

```
| Was before | Is now           |
|------------+------------------|
| Вождение   | Ð²Ð¾Ð¶Ð´ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ |
```

What could be the issue? I didn't change anything in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Have you try to set codepage to UTF-8?

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, how to do it?

Comment: Here is one example way: http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was fixed by setting in `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Instead of

```
export LANG=en_US
```